# How to sum up values from a Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to have the column 'IMPACT' to have their values summed up and by adding a line on the bottom called 'Total' with the integers values summed,excluding the NA and N/A.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
file = 'sheet.xlsx'
planilha = pd.read_excel(file,header=None,names=['Description','IMPACT'])

def my_function(text):
  key_string = 'IMPACT:'
  if '[' and ']' in text:   
    my_slice = text[text.find(key_string)+len(key_string):text.find(']')]
  else:
    my_slice = text[text.find(key_string)+len(key_string):]
  return my_slice

planilha['IMPACT'] = planilha['Description'].apply(lambda x: my_function(x))
```

This is the output:

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7cmQ.png)

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You should first edit your current function to get either the int you want or `np.nan`.

```py
def my_function(text):
    key_string = 'IMPACT:'
    if '[' and ']' in text:   
        my_slice = text[text.find(key_string)+len(key_string):text.find(']')]
    else:
        my_slice = text[text.find(key_string)+len(key_string):]
    try:
        my_slice = int(my_slice)
    except ValueErorr:
        my_slice = np.nan    
    return my_slice
```

After that, you should just be able to add a new row with `df.loc[]` and have that equal to the `df.sum()`.

```py
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()
```

This will sum all columns in the dataframe. If you don't want the other column summed, you can change that like this:

```py
df.loc['Total','Description'] = 'Do not sum this please'
```

`df.loc[]` will 'locate' a slice of the dataframe by name, with the first piece being the row and the second being the column. So using `df.loc['Total'] =` , you are locating the row called 'Total' (and creating it if it doesn't exist) and setting it to whatever.

When you do `df.loc['Total','Description'] =` , you are finding the intersection of the row called 'Total' and the column called 'Description', and setting that cell to whatever.

edit: adding a little piece to help with your current output.